# Syntax error when sending a Discord message using .VBS

Tags: vbscript

I recently wanted to create a script that would allow me to send messages from my different accounts without logging in/out of each one on Discord (I know that there is mutliple accounts capacity on Discord but you know... Challenge ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ )
So, I originally found a very basic script that you needed to edit each time you wanted to send a message. So I wanted to try to make a UI. I just pasted the send fuction in my code. Here's what I came up with (it's designed for french users so don't mind the text displayed ;) ):

```
On Error Resume Next

'Token selector dialogue box
account=InputBox("Merci d'indiquer le nom du compte ci-dessous","Discord CMD","")

'If user cancels, exit the program
if IsEmpty(account) Then
    WScript.Quit
end if

'Check if token is registered
Const ForReading = 1
Dim File, content, FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Function FileExists(FilePath)
    If fso.FileExists(FilePath) Then
        FileExists=CBool(1)
    Else
        FileExists=CBool(0)
    End If
End Function
If FileExists("database\accounts\"+account+".bin") Then
    'If the file exist, do nothing and continue the script
    WScript.Sleep(500)
Else
    'If the file doesn't exist, restart the script and display an error
    x=msgbox("This account has not be registered in the database. Please try again.", 0+16, "Error - Does not exist")
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Chat.vbs"
    WScript.Quit
End If

'Get the token related the account asked
Set File = fso.OpenTextFile("database\accounts\"+account+".bin", ForReading)
Token = File.ReadAll


'Loop
Do
    'Choose channel
    Echannel=InputBox("Merci d'indiquer l'identifiant du channel ci-dessous. Si il est identique, inscrivez 'Channel'","Discord CMD - " + account,"Channel")
    If (Echannel="Channel") Then
        'If the channel is the same as before, then we don't change it in the code
        WScript.Sleep(500)
    Else
        'If the channel is different, we change to the new value
        channels = Echannel
    End If

    'If user cancels, restart the program
    if IsEmpty(account) Then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Chat.vbs"
        WScript.Quit
    end if


    'The user enters his message
    text=InputBox("Merci d'indiquer le texte ci-dessous, faites OK pour l'envoyer","Discord CMD - " + account + " - Writing...","")

    'If user cancels, restart the program
    if IsEmpty(account) Then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Chat.vbs"
        WScript.Quit
    end if

    'We send the message
    Call commandeexercuter(channels,Token,text)
    Function commandeexercuter(channels,Token,text)
        Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
        sRequest = "{" & Chr(34) & "content" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & text & Chr(34) & "}"
        objXmlHttp.open "POST","https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" & channels &"/messages", False 
        objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", Token
        objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        objXmlHttp.send(sRequest)
    End Function
'We restart the loop
Loop
```

The only problem is that when I start the script, it returns an error and the last Function (the one that was working before) saying that the syntax isn't correct...

Can someone help me please?
Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a Function inside a Do Loop. You san simply move the Function declaration outside the loop, right after the last line:

```
    ' We send the message
    Call commandeexercuter(channels, Token, text)

'We restart the loop
Loop

Function commandeexercuter(channels, Token, text)
    Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    sRequest = "{" & Chr(34) & "content" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & text & Chr(34) & "}"
    objXmlHttp.open "POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" & channels & "/messages", False
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", Token
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objXmlHttp.send (sRequest)
End Function
```

I suggest you group all your functions together at the beginning or end of your script.

You can also simply place the `commandeexercuter` code in your loop directly since you are not using that function anywhere else:

```
    'If user cancels, restart the program
    If IsEmpty(account) Then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Chat.vbs"
        WScript.Quit
    End If

    Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    sRequest = "{" & Chr(34) & "content" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & text & Chr(34) & "}"
    objXmlHttp.open "POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" & channels & "/messages", False
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", Token
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    objXmlHttp.send (sRequest)

'We restart the loop
Loop
```